# How to create a gesture controlled rotating image for a UI

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I'm trying to figure out the best way to make an image rotate along
with a user's finger dragging it left or right.  I want to try and
match the rate a user's finger is moving with the rate the image is
rotating.

I've got the basic setup for my application going, with the menus and
whatnot I want to have, and that's all running great on the emulator,
I'm just not sure how to approach this part.

I can code all the logic I need for my app, I'm just not doing to well
designing the UI, I have a picture in mind, I've actually made a
couple mock images of it, I just can't figure out how to get it going
in Android, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to look at first at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

I am not really sure how to solve the problem with the real-life rotation but it seems OpenGL might help you.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

or maybe a solution through custom animations is possible?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html ( => http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html )

Tell us, how you solved it!